# @OrderColumn with nullable = true not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

The @OrderColumn is not working for nullable values
I have a Hibernate association like following:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(..some stuff..)
@OrderColumn(name = "pos", nullable = true)
@Fetch(org.hibernate.annotations.FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Child> child= new ArrayList<>(0);

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "child")
private List<Parent> parent = new ArrayList<>(0);
```

If I have an entry in the association table with NULL pos, it gives "null index column for collection:"

If I give default value as 0 in case of NULL pos, hibernate just returns 1 child with pos 0.

The database entries look like following:

parentTable

id

1

2

ChildTable

id parentId

1  1

2  1

3  1

4  2

5  2

parent_child_table

p_id c_id pos

1    1    0

1    2    1

1    3    2

2    4    null

2    5    null

Has anyone ever seen a similar issue and were able to resolve it?

Comment: Is it a `Primary Key`?

Comment: No - the OrderColumn "pos" is not a primary key, the parentId and childId are.

Comment: See if this [`SO answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6814072/2055998) is applicable to your case.

Comment: I am using hibernate 4 version, so was assuming the issue was resolved. Looks like it is not the case.
I may have to use an extra Column to get this to work.